# Identifying a number is an integer, fraction or decimal.

Tags: fractions, integers, decimal-expansion

Q- Is $\dfrac{24}{6}$ an integer,fraction,decimal?

I think it is an integer and a fraction. Its an integer because $\dfrac{24}{6}$ can be reduced to get an integer. It is not decimal because it doesn't contain decimal point.

Q- Is $1.0$ an integer, fraction,decimal?

I think it is an integer, a fraction and a decimal. Its an integer because $1.0$ is equal to $1$, a fraction because it can be reduced to $\dfrac{10}{10}=\dfrac{1}{1}$ and a decimal because it contains decimal point.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: $\frac{24}{6}=4.0?$

Comment: $\mathbf Z\subset\mathbf D \;\text{(decimal numbers) }\subset\mathbf Q$.

Comment: @Bernard, $\sqrt{2}$ in it decimal form is an irrational number, so shouldn't be that rational number a subset of decimal numbers.

Comment: Decimal is not a set of number, it is a way (base) to express a number. Any number can be expressed in decimal base. Also, in my opinion, the definition of fraction is too vague as any number can be expressed as ratio of two number, either rational or irrational.

Comment: by decimal I mean decimal numbers

Comment: Decimal numbers are those real numbers which a finite decimal expansion (e.g. $2.157$ is decimal, whereas $1/3=0.333\dots$ isn't.